# Can't use UIViewController for a tab bar view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I get the following error message when I attempt to use a class of subclass `UIViewController` on a view controller accessed by a tab bar:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyApp.StartUp 0x101717d20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

However, if I use a `UIPageViewController` there is no error message but the UI disappears and the background becomes black (disregarding the setting of the background colour in the storyboard).

I am using Swift. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not occur with normal view controllers outside of the tab bar.

Comment: Is there var named **name** inside **StartUp** VC

Comment: @Sh_Khan no there is not

Comment: ok search your VC in IB for an element associated with **name** and either remove the link to  it or declare an **IBOulet** that corresponds to this element type

Comment: @Sh_Khan thank you for your help! Fixed.